# Load a div when I right click on the table row only - context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a context menu when right click on the table row and I want to block right click on all the page except the table row. I want to load context menu via jQuery.

Here is my context menu div:

```
<div class="xContextMenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="next-chat">Accept Next Chat</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="next-response">Next Response</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="accept-chat">Accept Chat</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="refuse-chat">Refuse Chat</a></li>
        <li class="xDividerMenu">
            <img src="/live-person/web-area/assets/img/xContextDivider.png" alt="" />
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="invite-chat">Invite Chat</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">Engage</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">Block For Chat</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">Send Private Message</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">Chat Actions</a></li>
        <li class="xDividerMenu">
            <img src="/live-person/web-area/assets/img/xContextDivider.png" alt="" />
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="chat-history">Chat History</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">All Sessions history</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">Capture Visitor</a></li>
        <li class="xDividerMenu">
            <img src="/live-person/web-area/assets/img/xContextDivider.png" alt="" />
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">Suggest Content</a></li>
        <li class="xDividerMenu">
            <img src="/live-person/web-area/assets/img/xContextDivider.png" alt="" />
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">Cobrowser</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what about your jquery code? have you tried anything?

Comment: Google "load content into div ajax jquery."

Comment: i been tryng several solutions but they load contain content in the js. i want to load the complete div. here is my search result.
https://www.google.com/search?q=show+contextmenustrip+on+right+click&oq=on+right+click+show+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.9265j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=show+contextmenu+on+right+click+jquery&oq=show+contextmenu+on+right+click+jquery&gs_l=serp.3...5300.5300.1.5504.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0.0..1c.1.20.psy-ab.9Gp0RLWsS6M&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49478099%2Cd.bGE%2Cpv.xjs.s.en_US.MzTIAy2H0K0.O&fp=47044bcade7a2a4b&biw=1280&bih=923

Comment: @user1477388  i dont want to load into div. i want when i right click on the window i want to show a menu which the that div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a viable option:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QJHJ4/12/)

```
$(document).on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(e.target).is('li')) {
        $('#contextmenu').css({
            top:e.pageY + 'px',
            left:e.pageX + 'px'
        }).show();
    }
    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
   if (!$(e.target).is('#contextmenu')) $('#contextmenu').hide();
});
```

Comment: It's amazing how easy jQuery makes JavaScript look. Good example.

Answer (score 0):

For sections of the page where you want right click disabled:

```
$("#myid").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

For your table row's:

```
$("#myid").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    $('.xContextMenu').show();
});
```